# Draw lines with settings for line cap and line join

Tags: python, image, html, drawing

I need a library in Python which can draw lines with an option to choose line cap (e.g. round) and line join (e.g. round).

I am looking for something what works like HTML5 Canvas Drawing capabilities.

I looked at PIL, AggDraw and did not find the line cap and join options.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I found Cairo library, which I decided to use. You can read more about Cairo [here](http://cairographics.org/) and about PyCairo [here](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PyQt you can easily set those attributes and the application can be without a gui (e.g. just creating an image and saving for example to a file).

Just check the [QPainter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpainter.html) documentation about setting antialiasing (with setRenderHints) and the documentation about the [QPen](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpen.html) class to set cap and join style.

```
from PyQt4.Qt import *
import math

app = QApplication([])

img = QImage(256, 256, QImage.Format_RGB32)
dc = QPainter(img)
dc.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256, QColor(192, 192, 192))
dc.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing)
dc.setPen(QPen(QColor(128, 128, 192),
               12.0,
               Qt.SolidLine,
               Qt.RoundCap,
               Qt.RoundJoin))
pts = []
for i in xrange(7):
    t = i * 2 * 3 * math.pi / 7
    pts.append(QPointF(128 + 100 * math.cos(t),
                       128 + 100 * math.sin(t)))
dc.drawPolyline(QPolygonF(pts))
dc = None
img.save("output.png")
```

[image: Output of the example program]

Comment: Yes... I edited to add a complete example (the program creates an image and saves it to a .png file)

Comment: Looks interesting but I found Cairo library so I went with it.

Comment: Cairo is also a very nice library and of course a lot smaller (Qt has everything implemented, and then some more). The only problem I found when using Cairo was locating the correct libraries for windows and also the licensing terms that are IMO confusing if you want to use it in a closed source program.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're asking about HTML5 canvas, I assume you're outputting this to a web page. In that case, would you consider SVG graphics rather than Canvas? (personally I'd prefer SVG over Canvas, especially for drawing lines)

If you're okay with SVG, then you might want to look at [pySVG](http://codeboje.de/pysvg/) - it seems to meet your needs in terms of polygons and polylines.

Hope that helps.